# Unity Package Manager window and Services window showing font as white squares

Tags: unity-game-engine

After updating Mac OS to 13.0 Ventura some Unity editor windows appear with a font issue.[image: Screen capture of Package Manager showing the font issue]

Has anyone encountered this issue?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: That looks like an issue you should report to Unity.

Comment: Just asking if anyone encountered this issue since on Unity forums it takes way longer to get an answer. Will ask there too.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-editor-windows-content-texts-are-broken-on-macos.1353605/ and https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/text-is-replaced-with-white-squares-when-opening-package-manager

Answer (score 2):

As can be seen on this link (thanks Bart for showing it to me), changing the setting for Mac OS graphics under Player Settings -> Other Settings -> Desktop Build -> Auto graphics API to disabled and adding OpenGLCore as the first setting solves the problem.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-editor-windows-content-texts-are-broken-on-macos.1353605/